# How to do calculations from 2 dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I'm trying to do a calculation between two dataframes.

df1

| YN | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| Y | 100 |
| N | 50 |

df2

| Category | Factor |
| --- | --- |
| A | .10 |
| B | .20 |

I want to create a calculated field called Price where If df1 YN = Y then df2 A Factor is used, so 100 * .1

Then if df1 YN = N then df2 B Factor is used, so 50*.2

I've tried some combinations but only get errors. I'm such a n00b I don't even know what to Google.

Answer (score 0):

```
def calculate_price(row):
    if row['YN'] == 'Y':
        return row['Cost'] * df2[df2['Category'] == 'A']['Factor'].iloc[0]
    elif row['YN'] == 'N':
        return row['Cost'] * df2[df2['Category'] == 'B']['Factor'].iloc[0]
    df1['Price'] = df1.apply(calculate_price, axis=1)

    print(df1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is to create another column `factor` in `df1`:

```
df1['factor'] = 0.1
# set those rows with `N` to have value 0.2
df1.loc[df1['YN']=='N', 'factor'] = 0.2
```

Here you can simply take your calculation:

```
df1['result'] = df1['Cost'] * df1['factor']
```